# Mysterious(?) error in XML layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm trying to create a very simple list layout, following the CommonsWare examples found here: http://www.commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf.  Here are my relevant files:

RateListDemo.java

```
package my.ratelist;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class RateListDemo extends ListActivity {

private static final String[] items={"lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet", "consectetuer", "adipiscing",
    "elit", "morbi", "vel", "ligula", "vitae", "arcu", "aliquet", "mollis", "etiam", "vel", "erat", "placerat",
    "ante", "porttitor", "sodales", "pellentesque", "augue", "purus"};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, R.id.label, items));
    setContentView(R.layout.list);
}
}
```

list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/rate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numStars="3" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

So here's the really weird thing.  This code runs fine.  However, if I remove the RatingBar item from row.xml and leave just the TextView item, then it throws fatal errors upon running.  This makes no sense to me, especially since I have another application that runs a very similar layout scheme with no issue.  As you can see, there's no reference elsewhere in the code to the RatingBar item.  Also, if I switch the order of the RatingBar and TextView items in row.xml, it throws the same error.  What's the deal?

The initial error message is NullPointerException at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource.  I can provide the entire log if that helps.

EDIT:

Um, well after trying to run it in these different layout configurations and repeatedly getting fatal errors, they all now work.  But I didn't change anything except try to run it a few times.  I feel like that has happened to me before with XML.  So, the question remains: WTF?

Comment: Did you clean the project after moving or removing the order of your RatingBar? I think the R class id not always re-generated after changes in XML, when you try to run a project, so it may still have an old reference to that changed object..and that explains why after some more tries it start working.

Comment: Yeah, it definitely seems like there's some kind of artifact issue at work.  I've never had to clean projects before, but I'll try it next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, I tried this again, got the same fatal error, and then "cleaned" the project.  This appears to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

(You should normally post a stack trace when you have it.) I can already guess what it is though and it's quite straightforward. The code refers to this `RatingBar` and manipulates it. When you remove it, the code comes up with `null` when it looks it up and the error occurs.

Comment: Well, that would be the obvious answer and was the first thing I looked into.  Besides the three files above, there is the strings.xml and manifest.  They have zero references to the RatingBar.  As I said, this is a VERY simple layout.  I've stripped it way down in order to try to ferret out this error.  At this point, the RatingBar is just along for the ride.  Also, as I said, keeping the RatingBar but just switching the order of items in the layout also causes the fatal error.