# Error when changing layout

Tags: android, layout, compiler-errors

I've created a simple layout with few buttons and text fields. I keep receiving errors when I change something using graphical layout editor. Sometimes I just move the button and get errors during compilation like this:
*R cannot be resolved to a variable MainActivity.java   /USB_Host_test/src/gra/usb_host_test    line 103

I **have not deleted** anything, so unresolved variables must not appear.
Sometimes problems appear at runtime like was described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835137/mysterious-error-in-xml-layout). Cleaning the project doesn't help. Few times I've solved the problem by doing some minor changes to xml (adding/removing comments), but it's rather annoying. Is it a bug in an ADT or I'm doing something wrong?

I use ADT Build: v21.1.0-569685 from Android.com. Targe API level is 17, Min API level is 12.

Here is the xml code:

{

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btEnumerate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="70dip"
        android:text="Текст на отправку" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tbUSBRxData" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/SendF"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Medium Text1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btOpen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btEnumerate"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btEnumerate"
        android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:text="@string/Open" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/USBRead"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btEnumerate"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btOpen"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:text="USB Read" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/SendF"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/USBRead"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tbUSBD"
        android:text="USB Write" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tbUSBD"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/USBRead"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Получено от USB:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btRead"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/SendF"
        android:layout_below="@+id/SendF"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="Остновить службу" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btOpen"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tbUSBD"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btEnumerate"
        android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btEnumerate"
        android:autoLink="none"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:linksClickable="false"
        android:maxLines="10"
        android:minLines="4"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

}